# Only one table is created in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create database upon executing the python and the database only generates the first table but not other two. Could anyone help me realize what I might have done wrong?

Below is my code and the image is the picture of the .db file being created upon execution.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import os.path

import sqlite3

# Create database
dbTables = []
tableList = ["Choose Table"]
foreignKeys = {}
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('petData.db')

def createDB():
    if not db.open():
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setText("Error occurred during creating Database")
        retval = msg.exec_()
        return False
    query = QSqlQuery()

    query.exec_("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;")

    #Creating tables
    #Cat basic information table
    catInfo = """CREATE TABLE CatInfo (
                 Cat_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                 Cat_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                 Cat_Age INTEGER,
                 Cat_Weight INTEGER
                )"""
    dbTables.append(["CatInfo", catInfo])
    tableList.append("CatInfo")

    #Cat vaccination information table
    catVac = """CREATE TABLE Cat_Vaccine (
                CatVac_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                Cat_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                Cat_Vac_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                Cat_Vac_Date DATE,
                Cat_Vac_Description TEXT,
                FOREIGN KEY (Cat_ID) REFERENCES CatInfo(Cat_ID)
                )"""
    dbTables.append(["Cat_Vaccine", catVac])
    tableList.append("Cat_Vaccine")
    foreignKeys["Cat_Vaccine"] = [[1, "CatInfo", "Cat_ID", "Cat_Name"]]

    #Cat item inventory table
    inventory = """CREATE TABLE Inventory (
                   Inv_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                   Inv_Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                   Inv_Description TEXT,
                   Quantity CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                   FOREIGN KEY (Cat_ID) REFERENCES CatInfo(Cat_ID)
                   )"""
    dbTables.append(["Inventory", inventory])
    tableList.append("Inventory")
    foreignKeys["Inventory"] = [[1, "CatInfo", "Cat_ID", "Cat_Name"]]

    for i in range(len(dbTables)):
        if dbTables[i][0] not in db.tables():
            query.exec(dbTables[i][1])
    print(query.exec("PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEY_LIST(\"TESTING\")"))
    print("this is pk",db.primaryIndex("catInfo").name())

    return True
```

[SQLite Data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PzTO.png)

Comment: The code you presented will not create any tables since your `createDB()` function is never called.

Comment: Are you sure that no exception is raised?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Cat_Vaccine` and `Inventory` tables both have `FOREIGN KEY (Cat_ID)`, but neither table has a `Cat_ID` field.  You have to include a field definition before you can give a foreign key declaration.

And why is there a `Cat_Name` field in `CatVaccine`?  You should have `Cat_ID` and look up the cat's name.  That's 3NF.

Answer (score 0):

As it was answered above, your tables are missing fields CAT_ID, which you assign as foreign keys later. There's a fast code in C++ QT that repairs the problem(btw, I suggest using debug which will check the errors given from query)

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("petData.db");
    qDebug() << db.open();
    QSqlQuery q;
    q.exec("DROP TABLE Inventory");
    q.exec("DROP TABLE Cat_Vaccine");
    q.exec("DROP TABLE CatInfo");
    q.exec("CREATE TABLE CatInfo ( \
                 Cat_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \
                 Cat_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\
                 Cat_Age INTEGER,\
                 Cat_Weight INTEGER\
                )");
    qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
    q.exec("CREATE TABLE Cat_Vaccine (\
                CatVac_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\
                Cat_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,\
                Cat_Vac_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,\
                Cat_Vac_Date DATE,\
                Cat_Vac_Description TEXT,\
                Cat_ID INTEGER, \
                FOREIGN KEY (Cat_ID) REFERENCES CatInfo(Cat_ID)\
                )");
    qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
    q.exec("CREATE TABLE Inventory (\
                   Inv_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\
                   Inv_Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,\
                   Inv_Description TEXT,\
                   Quantity CHAR(50) NOT NULL,\
                   Cat_ID INTEGER, \
                   FOREIGN KEY (Cat_ID) REFERENCES CatInfo(Cat_ID)\
                   )");
    qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
```